# How do I assign a Bug or Product Backlog Item to a "Team"?

Tags: tfs, scrum

I have created a team underneath the Team Members section (in Team Explorer), but I cannot select this team from the drop down in my Bug. This drop down (highlighted text in image below) has no teams listed in it.

What am I doing wrong?

We are using the http://www.scrumforteamsystem.co.uk/ template for TFS 2008.

[image: Example of Bug in TFS, with no Team assigned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to TFS explorer, go to your project and right click on the project title and Select "Show Project Portal"

Once its loaded up in your browser, click on "Team Project Administration" Tab.

The team option is the second box on this page. Add your teams to there, and they will then appear in the dropdown within TFS Solution Explorer.

You will need to save any bugs first before you can assign it to a team though.

Answer (score 2):

The bug that you have in the image is a customized bug. Someone in the organization (maybe you) have changed to bug and added the Team field to the bug. The team that is available in the team explorer cannot be used in the work item, but you can use link that John added to show groups in the dropdown.

Another approach is to use a global list to determine the values for the team field. Adding a new team means that you have to add it to Team Explorer and to the global list.

In the new version of TFS (TFS 11), which you can preview at http://tfspreview.com, you can see that the team has become a first class citizin. If you want to see it in action, you can either go to [one of the sessions of //BUILD/](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-793T) or sign up for an account on TfsPreview.com.

Comment: We're using the Scrum for Team System template, and haven't changed anything on that. Any ideas where the drop down is looking for teams?

Comment: I don't know. You can use the Process Template Editor from the [TFS Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) to see what the definition of the Bug is. You can find there where the Team field gets its values from.

Answer (score 0):

See the blog post [Assigning a work item to a group in TFS](http://ivanfioravanti.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/assigning-a-work-item-to-a-group-in-tfs/).

This does require some minor customization of the work item types you're interested in changing.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to use the "Team" drop down already included in the Bug work item type.